Why can't I access the public method after overriding a protected method?
I have a question about access modifiers override.
First, let's look at the following code.
fun main() {
    val b: AAA = BBB()

    b.testA()
}

open class AAA {
    fun testA() {
        println("This is testA()")
    }
}

open class BBB : AAA()

result:
This is testA()
No problem with this code, b has printed testA() of class AAA.
Let's see the following code:
fun main() {
    val b: AAA = BBB()

    b.testA()
}

open class AAA {
    open fun testA() {
        println("This is testA()")
    }
}

class BBB : AAA() {
    override fun testA() {
        println("This is overridden testA() ")
    }
}

result:
This is overridden testA()
This code is also no problem.
Because testA() has been overridden, testA() of class BBB is called.
Now, here's the code I'm going to ask.
fun main() {
    val b: AAA = BBB()

    b.testA()
}

open class AAA {
    protected open fun testA() {
        println("This is testA()")
    }
}

class BBB : AAA() {
    public override fun testA() {
        println("This is overridden testA()")
    }
}

This code will not be executed. The IDE complains Cannot access 'testA': it is protected in 'AAA'.
Although testA() of AAA is protected, it was overridden as public in BBB, so I thought that naturally the overridden testA() of BBB would be called like the second code.
What's the problem?
Am I missing something?
What part of inheritance and access modifiers am I misunderstanding?

For virtual functions, there are two separate phases: resolution and selection.  Resolution is purely static; it is about "what method does it look like I am trying to call".  This is often a method in a superclass, such as List::size.  Selection is dynamic; it is about what override is invoked at run time.  Both the selected method and resolved method need to be accessible to the caller.

For background, see this article about polymorphism.


Although testA() of AAA is protected, it was overridden as public in BBB, so I thought that naturally the overridden testA() of BBB would be called like the second code.

The misunderstanding is about when things happen.
A method call is "dispatched dynamically" with respect to overrides. What this means is that the correct override is chosen at the very last minute when you actually run the code. In your case, the implementation of the method in BBB is used (because b actually points to an instance of BBB, a.k.a an object of type BBB). This is how polymorphism works, and this is why, indeed, you can see This is overridden testA() in your compiling snippets.
However, the compiler (and the IDE) doesn't run your code, so it can only use information that is known to be true at compile time. What matters in this case is the type of the reference variable b that you use to call the method testA().
In your last snippet, the type of b is explicitly marked as AAA, so the compiler analyses your code based on that, and the method will be resolved to AAA.testA() for the purpose of the compilation. The visibility will also be checked based on this: AAA doesn't have a visible testA method. You can actually see this in action if you try to navigate to the function definition in an IDE (it will lead you to the definition in AAA, not the one in BBB).
In simpler terms, you can imagine that the compiler sees b as an AAA without any assumptions about the actual value that it will point to when the code runs. This is literally what this means to declare the type AAA explicitly: you're telling the compiler to ignore the extra information that it had about b, and to only consider the API available on all objects of type AAA.
If you want your last snippet to compile, you would have to declare b of type BBB (or remove the explicit type and let the compiler infer the type to BBB automatically).
fun main() {
    val b: BBB = BBB() // or simply val b = BBB()

    b.testA()
}


So, at the compilation phase (maybe IDE? Right?), it is based on the type of the reference variable, and at the runtime phase, it is based on the type(instance) that the reference variable actually points to (overriding also operates at runtime). So, before compilation, did the IDE occur an error due to the type of the reference variable? If this is correct, it's because I didn't know what worked in the runtime and compilation phase.

You can consider the IDE analysis/highlighting the same way as the compilation phase (it's literally running the compiler frontend to analyze your code). So yes, the IDE will show an error because it's not running your code yet. It shouldn't make assumptions about the actual instance that will be there at runtime (you actually explicitly tell the compiler/IDE to consider b as an AAA by specifying the type like this)

thank you It was very helpful. I'm not sure if my comment accurately understands your answer.

To make it more explicit: b is of type AAA, so accessing b.testA() is not allowed because it is protected.
It doesn't matter what that b object actually is, you can only use the members that are defined by AAA. After all, b could also be some other AAA instance that does not have an accessible testA() function.
If you know that b is actually not only an AAA but also a BBB, you can cast it like this:
val reallyB: BBB = b as BBB

Although it is the same object under the hood, the variable reallyB is now of type BBB so you can access any of its members. testA is now public so this works:
reallyB.testA()


Thank you. But even in the second code, b is of type AAA, but didn't it use testA of BBB?

You only ever have one object, and that is of type BBB (and also of type AAA, since BBB extends AAA). So whenever testA is called "This is overridden testA()" is printed. The problem with your initial code is that it cannot be called because that function isn't visible: You use the interface of AAA (not its implementation, though). That is what changes when casting to BBB: Now you can use the interface of BBB, and that has a visible testA() function.

Succinctly, a variable is treated by the compiler as the type it is currently specified to be in the code. This is a core principle of object oriented languages.
When you assign a BBB instance to a variable of type AAA, you are telling the compiler you want it to be treated as an AAA.
Kotlin’s smart casting loosens this a bit. When your code uses conditionals that can narrow down the type, the compiler will treat the variable as the narrower type. But if you upcast or assign to a more generally typed variable, it will go back to the less specific type.

thank you. But I have a question. So why does it call testA of BBB even though b is of type AAA in the second code?

It calls whatever testA is defined for the instance you’re calling it on. b is known to the compiler to be an AAA but that doesn’t mean its insides have been gutted and replaced with its parent type’s definition. It just means that all the compiler knows about it is that it is an AAA (which means it could be any subtype of AAA).  Look up and read about the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Or another way to put it: at that spot in code, the compiler only knows that it fulfills the contract of what an AAA is, so it won’t let you use extra features of BBB. That doesn’t mean it isn’t a BBB and won’t exhibit its own BBB behaviors. It is still that specific instance of BBB.
